# How do I make this line's width randomly grow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to learn Javascript and integrate it into a webpage however when trying to use a JavaScript random function that changes the size of a line on click nothing happens?

```js
function randomnumber(min, max) {
    var rn = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    document.getElementById("rain").style.width = rn;
}
```

```css
body {
  background:#000000; 
}

.line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 40px;
  background: white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="rain" onclick="randomnumber(1px,100px)">
    <div class="size">
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The parameters in your function have to be integers to apply arithmetics on it.
- If you are setting a width you have to add the unit like `px`.
- In your CSS you are setting the width of the element having the class `line`, but in your JS your are changing the value of the element having the id `rain` - to change the width you've set in css you can use the `querySelector` provided below.

```js
function randomnumber(min, max) {
  var rn = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  document.querySelector('#rain .line').style.width = rn + 'px';
}
```

```css
body {
   background:#000000; 
   margin: 100px;
}

.line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  background: white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="rain" onclick="randomnumber(1,100)">
  <div class="size">
    <div class="line">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you consider the `1px` and `100px` to be number, but the type of `1px` and `100px` is string. Also, you can't use `1px` and 100px to do Math.

Also, another problem make your code won't work is your are trying to assign the width to parent element of `line` (the `rain`) and since rain doesn't have any style, it won't work as well. You should directly apply style for `line`

```js
function randomnumber(min, max) {
  var rn = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  document.querySelector(".line").style.width = rn+'px';
}
```

```css
body {
  background:#000000; 
}

.line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 40px;
  background: white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id=rain onclick="randomnumber('1','100')" >
        <div class="size">
            <div class="line">
            </div>
        </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use as a parameter of a javascript function a css value such as `100px` or something like `1rem`.

In the 'rain' div use this code:

```html
//...
<div id="rain" onclick="randomnumber(1, 100)">
    //...
</div>
//...
```